# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Rake::FileTask into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I trying to generate CSV file on server, but when I run `generate_file`

```
def generate_file
    CSV.open(file, 'w', write_headers: true, headers: column_headers) do |writer|
      writer << ['Auto merging list']
      @auto_merging_rows.each_with_index { |row, _index| writer << filled_row(row) }
      writer << ['Manual handling list']
      @manual_handling_rows.each { |row| writer << filled_row(row) }
    end
  end
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Rake::FileTask into String
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1265:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1265:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1265:in `open'
    from (irb):150:in `generate_file'
```

What can be reason? In other parts of code we use CSV same way, but there is no errors.

The server we using here run in Kubernetes, I suspect the problem can be according to it. But when I run this CSV generation without method calling, everything is going well.

One more interesting detail - this method should be called in Sidekiq, and Sidekiq worker is finished without any error. But the file is not generating.

Comment: Did you set the variable `file`? Because if the file path is nil, you will also get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in hardware. The operating memory limit was expired thats why container have interrupted the job.